# Slow processing when render helper link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm displaying 3k users. When render helper link_to process rendering slowing.  It takes a lot of time.

it is my template

```
- @user.each do |user|
      %tr
        %td= link_to_user_modal user
        %td.text-right
          = link_to edit_user_path(user.id),
                    class: 'btn btn-default btn-xs',
                    title: 'Edit' do
            %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-pencil

          = link_to user,
                  method: :delete,
                  title:  'Delete',
                  data:   { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete #{user}?" },
                  class:  "btn btn-danger btn-xs" do
            %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash
```

Comment: _"I'm displaying 3k users. [...] It takes a lot of time."_ – coincidence? ;-)

Comment: @Stefan without this helper it takes 7 second.

Comment: Oh, I see, just one of the `link_to`'s or all three?

Comment: @Stefan with all three `link_to` it itakes 47 second, without all three 7 second. Why such difference?

Comment: Render time in rails or in your browser?

Comment: @Stefan load time page  in my browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rendering plain html instead of using the helper improves considerably the time needed to render.
It's not as much "link_to" that burdens the rendering but more of the path_helper. Although placing raw html in the view is quicker than any of both:

```
<a href="the/path/the_helper/would/render/#{user.id}" target="_blank" class="whatever">Edit</a>
```

instead of

```
link_to path_helper
```

or even (since the helper is the biggest culprit)

```
<a href="#{path_helper}" target="_blank">edit</a>
```

[check ruby-prof for the call trace - the only line that was changed was link_to to pure html with the id inserted dynamically into the href string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u89OF.jpg)

I also tested the  tag with the href using the path helper, and though it's faster than link_to with the path helper, it's slower than  with href as a string. You can also see that I didn't call .html_safe on the concanated href, which should render it even faster in the  tag as well.

Comment: The client does not want used will_paginate

Comment: Have you tried using directly the html instead of the link_to helper? <a data-confirm="Are you sure you want to delete #{user.name}?" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/whatever/path/#{user.id}">Delete</a> ??? for all three link_to's ofc. And isn't this wrong: "Are you sure you want to delete #{user}?" shouldn't it be user.name or something?

Comment: No, I have not tried it. I'm going to try now. As for `User.name`, I have the to_s alias and the getter method in the model, so everything is fine.

Comment: Your advice has been helped. thank you very much. Please, update answer. I will mark as solve

Comment: @Andiskiy done and added screenshot of the ruby-prof output for link_to with path helper and <a> with dynamically created href string (no path_helper)